# Google Docs Blinking Cursor "kix-cursor-caret"

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-docs

I love google docs but I find a blinking cursor very distracting. The new version of google docs doesn't obey the operating system setting for displaying a solid (non-blinking) cursor.

I see that the cursor is really just a div of class "kix-cursor-caret" where the display property is just from "none" to "inline" on some sort of javascript timer somewhere that causes the cursor to appear to blink.

Does anybody have any idea which javascript line/command is causing the css property to be changed and displaying the blinking. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Regardless of whether you find a solution, I'd suggest submitting a feature request to Google Docs.

Comment: I did a couple of times over the last year. If you search for google docs cursor blink rate you'll see my messages. But maybe I'm not submitting my requests to the right place. Do you have a link to the site for feature requests?

Comment: You can suggest a new feature here: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Docs/label?lid=73938c871fa993cd&hl=en

Comment: Some members of the Google Docs team did a Q&A on Reddit a few months ago: http://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/hylnw/were_five_members_of_the_google_docs_team_ask_us/. There's a a chance there may be something helpful in there. I haven't found a better place to request features: my searches just found what I assume are your requests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, this works for me with Stylebot in Chrome:

```
.kix-cursor {
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

None of the current answers worked for me using Firefox + Stylish.
I found a working answer at userstyles.org [1]:

```
.docs-text-ui-cursor-blink {
        animation-name: none;
}
```

[1] https://userstyles.org/styles/125112/google-docs-disable-cursor-blink

Comment: I would love to see this solution ranked higher in Google's results for "google docs cursor blink", thank you all who have contributed!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this can actually be solved with CSS. This rule worked for me:

```
.kix-cursor-caret: inline !important;
```

I suppose you could add this to some kind of user stylesheet, but I've actually never made one before.

Answer (score 1):

Ian's answer didn't work for me. I used this CSS:

```
.kix-cursor-caret: {
    opacity: 1 !important
}
```

and put it in a user stylesheet managed by the [Stylebot Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha).

This stopped the madness in the current version of Google Docs.

Comment: How to make it work with Stylebot in most recent version of HTML markup of GoogleDocs?